# jspdf not working on local server - nothing happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I just downloaded the jsPDF files from paralaxx.ax and wanted to test it on my local server (MAMP). On their site everything worked fine. 
But on my local server the example files from the download do not work. I also tried it myself with my own file. But nothing happens. 
In the examples when i click on the button "Run Code" nothing happens :(
I turned on the JavaScript Console in Firefox and the only error I get is:
ReferenceError: demoTwoPageDocument is not defined ...

I checked the files which are included, every file is found and linked the right way.

Do you have a idea what I made wrong?

joachim

Comment: Does it perform ajax? ajax to the filesystem typically fails because the filesystem is considered cross-origin and doesn't return CORS headers.

Comment: I don't really know if it performs ajax ... but i dont think that causes the error

Comment: read the source? look at your console?

Comment: OK I checked the jspdf.js file - I can't find anything looking like ajax